# AWS lambda blocking CORS requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, python-3.x, lambda

I know there's already a bunch of the same questions but I have tried what is the solution in those without success. I'm calling the lambda from localhost.

I have enabled CORS in my lambda.

I have these headers in my lambda response:

```
{"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": True,
                "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST"}
```

These are the headers I'm sending in my request:

```
headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  }
```

What could go wrong here that is different from the solutions in the other threads?

Image that shows I have enabled CORS
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: What is the specific error message that the browser gives about CORS?

Comment: "I have these headers in my lambda response" — Have you, using the Network tab in the browser's developer tools, confirmed that the browser is receiving those headers?

Comment: @Quentin Access to fetch at X from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: @Reyno that's what true looks like in Python

Comment: @Quentin Had a look now and it's not present in the OPTIONS request. I wonder why when I have enabled it

Comment: Likely you didn't enable it properly, but I can't see how you configured API gateway

Comment: @Quentin I have updated the OP with a picture that shows it has been enabled

Comment: Aren't those red triangles errors that it tells you you need to deal with?